# Checar se o valor de um objeto de um certa classe foi mudado

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Quero que quando um valor for mudado dentro de um objeto de certa classe, outro mude também.
Exemplo:

```js
class minhaClasse{
  constructor(valor1, valor2){
    this.valor1 = valor1
    this.valor2 = valor2
    this.valores = {
      valor1: this.valor1,
      valor2: this.valor2
    }
  }
}

var meuObjeto = new minhaClasse(2,4)
console.log(meuObjeto.valor1, meuObjeto.valores)

meuObjeto.valor1++ // ou meuObjeto.valor1 = 3
//log esperado => 3 {"valor1": 3, "valor2": 4}
console.log(meuObjeto.valor1, meuObjeto.valores)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar *getters* para fazer isso. Esses valores de `this.valores` podem ser um ponteiro protegidos de escrita (read-only) dos valores `this.valor1` e `this.valor2`.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
class minhaClasse {
  constructor(valor1, valor2) {
    this.valor1 = valor1
    this.valor2 = valor2
    const self = this;

    this.valores = {
      get valor1() {
        return self.valor1;
      },
      get valor2() {
        return self.valor2;
      }
    }
  }
}

var meuObjeto = new minhaClasse(2, 4)
console.log(meuObjeto.valor1, meuObjeto.valores)

meuObjeto.valor1++; // ou meuObjeto.valor1 = 3
// log esperado 3 {"valor1": 3, "valor2": 4}
console.log(meuObjeto.valor1, meuObjeto.valores)
meuObjeto.valores.valor1 = 200;
console.log(meuObjeto.valores); // dá  {"valor1": 3, "valor2": 4}
```

Comment: Acabaram de me responder no StackOverflow gringo, responderam a mesma coisa que você. De qualquer jeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: @LuísHNrique [ambas ao mesmo tempo!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63148485/2256325). Pois, getters é a maneira mais simples e como escrevi na resposta esses valores não podem ser mudados se configurados da maneira correta.

Comment: eu tinha tentado usar `get valor1(){ return this.valor1 }`, não tinha pensado em criar uma variável pro `this`